# ¿Porque no se muestra informaciòn del servidor MySQL? | php MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola comunidad tengo una duda con mi còdigo.
Estoy tratando de que me muestre la versiòn del server pero no muestra la informaciòn del server ni otros datos con otras funciones de las cuales e realizado testeos.
Mi còdigo es el siguiente:

```
$server=  "localhost";
$usuario= "fake_user";
$psswd=   "fake_password";
$db=      "fake_users";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $psswd, $db);

if(!$conn) {
   die("Error de conexion:") . mysqli_connect_errno(); 
   exit();
  }

if($conn) {
   die("Conexiòn exitosa:") . mysqli_get_server_version($conn) ;
  }
```

Tengo la teorìa de que el problema radica en el archivo php.ini leì en el manual de php
sobre el còdigo de error sobre la funciòn  mysqli_connect_errno() pero tampoco lo muestra
y observe esto  "mysqli_connect_errno(): int"  pero no dice nada mas al respecto. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando mal `die()`.

La función `die` (*o [`exit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)*) toma como parámetro una cadena o un número el cual será enviado como salida al cliente y **acto seguido se detiene el proceso**.

Tus mensajes no aparecen y no van a aparecer porque estas intentando concatenarlos después del llamado de `die()`.

#### Solución:

Enviar toda la cadena como parámetro de la función.

```
// Ejemplo
die("Conexiòn exitosa:" . mysqli_get_server_version($conn));
```

Comment: lol muchas gracias amigo me informarè mas sobre estos temas.